# Можно ли в предложении использовать одно местоимение два раза?

Tags: грамотная-речь, местоимение

В первом местоимение **я** использовано один раз, а во втором два раза. Первое предложение, конечно, правильно составлено, а второе?

1. Что ж, я наивно думал, что смогу что-то изменить.
2. Что ж, я наивно думал, что я смогу что-то изменить.

Comment: Я спел тогда ещё — я думал, это ближе —
«Про юг» и «Про того, кто раньше с нею был»…

Comment: Спасибо. А так? МОЙ ПЕССИМИЗМ ЗАСТАВИЛ МЕНЯ ПОВЕРИТЬ, ЧТО ЭТО НЕ СРАБОТАЕТ. НО, НАИВНО ДУМАЛ Я — Я СМОГУ СОВЕРШИТЬ ИЗМЕНЕНИЕ.

Comment: Обособить «наивно думал я» можно и запятыми, и тире, но всё же симметрично.

Answer (score 2):

Во втором излишний повтор местоимения. В английском, французском без такого повтора никак не обойтись, а в русском лучше его избегать после союза.